# JS Adding up number in constructor function

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have run into a problem. For simplicity I will keep this question formatted like it was a school assignment, but my problem stems from accessing API data where when I create a new Contructor function that keeps tally over the total price of all items created this way. Example:

```
function Item(name, price, orderID) {
    var totalPrice;

    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.orderID = orderID;

    // This is where the addToTotalPrice function should do something
    function addToTotalPrice() {
        totalPrice += price;
    }();
}
```

But I cannot get a function like this inside a constructor function to run, even in a simple case like this. How can I make sure that this works?

Thanks!

-- The Stupid Pony! :P

Comment: `totalPrice` is `undefined`. If `price` is a numher, `totalPrice` will be `NaN` afterwards. I guess your "simplification" transformed the code into "nonsense"

Comment: You‘re neither calling the function, nor assigning it to the instance, nor returning a value. if you want to sum all item prices, it might be easier to write a function that just loops over an arra with items and sums their price

Comment: e.g. `(items) => items.reduce((prc,itm) => prc + itm.price,0)`. Just pass it an array of items. Yo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1: You are not calling the function properly.

2: totalPrice is undefined

Update your code to:

```
let totalPrice = 0;
(function(){
        totalPrice += price;
})();
```

Edit: Thanks @jonas. for pointing out the 2nd point.

Comment: 1) he is. 2) no it is not.

Comment: @JonasW. I'm so sorry. You are right. I meant totalPrice. Updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This may suit you. Ping if I misunderstood your answer.

```js
function Item(){};
Item.totalPrice=0;
Item.create = function(name, price, orderID) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.orderID = orderID;
    Item.totalPrice+=this.price;
}
console.log(Item.totalPrice);
var item1 = Item.create("pen",10,123);
var item2 = Item.create("paper",10,124);
console.log(Item.totalPrice);
```